# How to Generate Static Connection String by Remote desktop Protocol

Tags: c#, tcp, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-services

I have implemented Remote desktop Protocol terminal services in c#. Server generates the connection string and client uses this connection string to connect with a server.

The problem is that each time i start a server , a new connection string is generated. is there any way that we could generate a static connection string .

My both PC are connected with wire with each other...

Comment: what server is this ? is this a machine ? or sql server ? tcp ip connection is made using the ip address of the server that too static ip address. so what exactly changes in the server ?

Comment: Server is just simply another PC.

Comment: I have made a just a Remote Desktop Sharer program in which there are two pc 1 is server and 1 is client. Client can see and control desktop of server pc.

Comment: by new connection string u mean , does it create a new string with new ip address ?

Comment: Both PC are connected with each other through cable and internet settings is set to automatic.

Comment: Connection String generated is in this format ...........   <E><A KH="1B57AukieH1kB/H0yRK2EipvyeI=" ID="Test"/><C><T ID="1" SID="1138701287"><L P="5513" N="fe80::cdf8:be9c:7160:fe20%30"/><L P="5514" N="fe80::2d37:96ad:55f5:e422%31"/><L P="5515" N="fe80::14e1:18ef:3f57:fef3%15"/><L P="5516" N="2001:0:5ef5:79fb:14e1:18ef:3f57:fef3"/><L P="5517" N="fe80::492b:f1e2:a55a:9382%11"/><L P="5518" N="192.168.146.1"/><L P="5519" N="192.168.150.1"/><L P="5520" N="192.168.1.12"/></T></C></E>

Comment: Next time i again generate connect connection string it is below...

<E><A KH="1B57AukieH1kB/H0yRK2EipvyeI=" ID="Test"/><C><T ID="1" SID="2908045317"><L P="5728" N="fe80::cdf8:be9c:7160:fe20%30"/><L P="5729" N="fe80::2d37:96ad:55f5:e422%31"/><L P="5730" N="fe80::492b:f1e2:a55a:9382%11"/><L P="5731" N="fe80::450:18ef:d8df:ddfe%15"/><L P="5732" N="2001:0:5ef5:79fb:450:18ef:d8df:ddfe"/><L P="5733" N="192.168.146.1"/><L P="5734" N="192.168.150.1"/><L P="5735" N="192.168.1.12"/></T></C></E>


There is change in both strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the connection string, there is global ipv6 address as seen starting with prefix "2001:". This address changes if the machine reboots or the internet ipv4 address changes after which the connection string is not valid. Windows has PNRP names which are 128-bit unique name to a computer & resolves to appropriate ipv6 address using p2p DNS resolving mechanism. You can check the below link to find out the pnrp name of your computer using which you can RDP to it any time.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb962088.aspx

Comment: Many other parameters are also changing almost string changes when new string is generated ... is there any way to use same string ??

Comment: Once you figure out the ipv6 address with PNRP name. You can establish direct connection to your application running in the machine & create an ne w invitation every time its expires.

Comment: oh that means after figuring out PNRP name i can direct connection to application over lan ..??